# how can I express a median in terms of barycentric coordinates?

Tags: computational-geometry

I am trying to understand relationship between Median and [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system).

here is a figure (fig_1) comes from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry))

[image]

that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56337107/11074017) gives a good explanation and I am trying to connect the notation in that post to fig_1.

> Vertex of such small triangle at the first median has B.C.(baricentric coordinates) like
>   `(g,f,f)`, where `g+f+f=1`, at the second median `(f,g,f)`, and
>   `(f,f,g`) at the third one. We can see that for `g=1/3` triangle size
>   is zero (coefficient `cf= 0`), for `g=1` triangle is equal to large
>   triangle `(cf = 0)`.

in this context, is it correct to consider point E as `(g,f,f)`?

Comment: Every point on the line segment $AE$ has barycentric coordinates of the form $(g,f,f)$ where $g+2f=1$. In particular, $E$ corresponds to $g=0,f=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a way to understand the situation is as follows. Let $x,y,z$ be the normed barycentric coordinates of $O$, $x+y+z=1$. By definition:
$$
O = xA+yB+zC\ .
$$
(Understand this either using affix points $A,B,C$, or using a "testing point" $P$ and rewrite with vectors the relation as $PO =xPA+yPB+zPC$.)

These $x,y,z$ are barycentric coordinates, thus coordinates  "in the plane", and the argument reduces them, their symmetry to one "on the line". Let us see how. Just rewrite:
$$
\begin{aligned}
O &= xA+(y+z)E\ ,\text{ where}\\
E &= \frac y{y+z}B+\frac z{y+z}C\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(From the first relation, $E$ is on $OA$, from the second relation it is on $BC$, so it is indeed the point $E$ in the picture.)

Since $E$ is the middle of $BC$, we must have the corresponding coordinates "in the line" equal, so $y/(y+z)=z/(y+z)$, so $y=z$.

By symmetry to $y=z$ we also get $x=y$ (and $x=z$), so $x=y=z=1/3$.

Note that already knowing the porportion $OE:AE$ lets us know the $x$.

Comment: thanks for your answer! is $O = xA+yB+zC\$ in Cartesian coordinates or in barycentric coordinates?

Comment: I will give an answer using examples. See also http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html for more on trilinear and barycentric coordinates. For the intersection of medians we have the (not normalized) coordinates $(1:1:1)$. To make them sum to one, we normalize to $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$. Then the relation $G=\frac 13A+\frac13 B+\frac 13C$ (using $G$ instead of $O$) holds in cartesian coordinates, for instance, if $A(1,2)$, $B(2,3)$, $C(3,-2)$, then we simply build $\frac 13(A+B+C)=\left(\frac 13(1+2+3),\ \frac 13(2+3-2)\right)$.

Comment: A very good description is here: http://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/bary/bary-short.pdf